# JavaFX - ScrollPane and setting the size

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I know this is probably obvious, but I've searched and found no solution. I want to have an anchorpane wrapped in a scrollpane. In that scrollpane. I wanted the actual view size to be 1000x1000 but the scrollable area to be 1920x1080. I want the anchorpane to be 1920x1080 (the full size of the scrolled scrollpane).

First question: How do I set the scrollable area size? I set HMax: 1920, HMin: 0, HValue: 0 and VMax: 1080 VMin: 0, VValue: 0. This doesn't seem to be doing the trick, and I only set these values based off information I loosely understood found on the javafx api.

Second question: How do I set the anchorpane to the full (scrollable) size of the scrollpane? I wrapped it in the scrollpane(I'm doing this in scenebuilder) but I am not sure it will automatically fill the entire scrollpane, including when the scroll pane is scrolled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the preferred size of the AnchorPane to 1920x1080. ScrollPane resizes its content to the content's preferred size.

Set the preferred viewport size of the ScrollPane to 1000x1000

```
anchorPane.setPrefSize(1920, 1080);
scrollPane.setPrefViewportWidth(1000);
scrollPane.setPrefViewportHeight(1000);
```

Comment: I knew it had to be more obvious than I was thinking. Thank you!